# How to compare 3 different arrays in PHP laravel or Java Script

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have three different arrays. First array

```
$years = [2015,2016,2017,2018];
```

Second array

```
$users = ["a","b","c"];
```

Third array

```
$data = [
  {"year":2015,"user":"a","amount":100},
  {"year":2016,"user":"a","amount":90},
  {"year":2017,"user":"b","amount":70},
  {"year":2018,"user":"c","amount":80}
];
```

Now I want to compare all those arrays and get the data for each user for each year i.e if a user does not exists in particular year then 0 should be inserted in that place in below format

Desired output:

```
{"name":"a", "data":[100,90,0,0]},
{"name":"b", "data":[0,0,70,0]},
{"name":"c", "data":[0,0,0,80]}
```

My code so far is

```
foreach($yeararray as $year)
{
    foreach($usersarray as $user)
    {
        if($user == $data["user"]) && ($year == $data["year"]))
        {
            array_append($newarray, $user);
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($newarray, $user);
        }
    }
}
```

but it is not working I think my code is somewhere wrong.

Comment: what is the output of your current code then?

Comment: the third array is not a valid php array

Comment: Can you please explain more your point? Sorry, I am unable to find the issue in array.

Comment: If my code is wrong, can some share me the code for this logic:  comparing array#1 and array#2 with array#3. If match the 'user' value & 'amount' for a given value of 'year', insert the amount for matching 'year' value. Else insert zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a new array of objects and assign the value by using indexOf for the right index.

```js
var years = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018],
    users = ["a", "b", "c"],
    data = [{ year: 2015, user: "a", amount: 100 }, { year: 2016, user: "a", amount: 90 }, { year: 2017, user: "b", amount: 70 }, { year: 2018, user: "c", amount: 80 }],
    result = users.map(user => ({ user, years: years.map(_ => 0) }));
    
    
data.forEach(({ year, user, amount }) => result[users.indexOf(user)].years[years.indexOf(year)] = amount);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the `users` array and retrieve the desired result. Note that adding a new user (`d`), justs returns an array of zeros:

```js
var data = [
  {"year":2015,"user":"a","amount":100},
  {"year":2016,"user":"a","amount":90},
  {"year":2017,"user":"b","amount":70},
  {"year":2018,"user":"c","amount":80}
];
var years = [2015,2016,2017,2018];
var users = ["a","b","c","d"]; // Added an extra user just for the demonstration

// Iterate users
var result = users.map(function(user) {
  var thisData = [];
  // Iterate years
  for (var i in years) {    
    var item = 0;
    // Filter out the item for specific year and user
    var rec = data.filter(function(dt) {
      return dt.year == years[i] && dt.user == user;
    });    
    if (rec.length === 1) {
      item = rec[0].amount;
    }
    thisData.push(item);
  }
  return {
    name: user,
    data: thisData
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let users = ["a", "b", "c"];
let year = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018];
let data = [
  {"year":2015,"user":"a","amount":100},
  {"year":2016,"user":"a","amount":90},
  {"year":2017,"user":"b","amount":70},
  {"year":2018,"user":"c","amount":80}
];

let answer = [];
users.forEach(user => {
  let dataArray = [];

    year.forEach(year => {
      if(data.some(dat => dat.year === year && dat.user===user)){
        dataArray.push(data.find(dat => dat.year === year && dat.user===user).amount)
      }else{
        dataArray.push(0);
      }
    });

  answer.push({"user": user, "data": dataArray});
});

console.log(answer);
```

First we loop thru `users`, for each of the user, we loop thru each of the `year`, using the current user and year, we can find existance in `data` Array, and finally compute the result